# Buffer overflow - Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, buffer-overflow, exploit

I'm learning buffer overflow exploiting. I wrote a vulnerable program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[80];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

Very simple program. The idea is to overwrite the return address that's used to return to the libc function `start_main`. Everything went fine and I used GDB to verify that the return address is overwritten with the right address that points to the `shellcode` in the memory.

But when I'm suppose to get a shell this appears:

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xbffff178 in ?? ()`

`0xbffff178` is the return overwritten return address and it does point to the `shellcode` I'm pretty sure. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have a no-execute stack, which prohibits code from being executed from certain address ranges. You need to compile with `-z execstack` to force the stack to be executable.

Comment: How could the stack require execution rights if all is being changed there is the return address to a different function?

Comment: He's writing both the return address and the shellcode to the string buffer, which lives on the stack.